# Can the memoryless property be applied to all probability distributions (both discrete and continuous)?

Tags: distributions

I am brand new to *Cross Validated* and have a question about memoryless properties on probability distributions.

Here is my question, to understand how and when to apply this property of statistics:

> **If an insurance company insures losses which are uniform between 0 and 20 (in thousands) and, the insureds' policies have deductibles of 2 (thousand), what is the variance in payment to 100 customers' policies?**

Since the payment and loss functions are both uniform, but the payment is 0 if the losses are less than 2 (thousand), the memoryless property can be applied by a 'shift' in the 'uniform' graph for a loss between zero and 20 (thousand) to a payment between 0 and 18 (thousand) per policy.

All this is to prepare for the first preliminary exam to be an actuary, just FYI.

Comment: What statistical property holds when a distribution is memoryless?  (Welcome to Cross Validated, by the way.)

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty. The question's premise that "discrete and continuous" encompasses "all probability distributions" is false, so the question is - as it stands - impossible to answer. It's also weirdly phrased. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... 
However, you should be able to state what memorylessness means in terms of an equality relating a conditional and an unconditional probability, and I am guessing you have been given at examples of distributions with the property. What do you know?

Comment: Your statement doesn't make any sense to me. How do you add "c" to *an event*??

Comment: By the way, while it's good that you state the source of the question (that it's a practice question for an exam), you don't need to tell us that you need to pass or who requires that you pass.

Comment: Hi Glen - I am new, as in I registered today for _Cross Validated_. I am learning how to use the features of this site, so please do understand. I also am not familiar with how to best ask questions. I guess, when I add "c" to an event, it has no meaning, right? For example, in order to be more specific on my question, suppose that losses on vehicles follow an exponential distribution with mean of 1000, "Z" is the random variable to represent the losses, how can I use the memoryless property to find the Variance of (Z | Z<1500)? What if these losses are uniform, can memoryless property apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question about which distributions the *memoryless property* apply. I conducted further research on this and found that the memoryless property only holds for geometric and exponential distributions. The reason is kind of obvious and I now understand that the behavior of the *probability density function* curve (in the case of the $exponential$ distribution) and the *probability mass function* graph (concerning the $geometric$ distribution) will not change if we want to find the probability of a random variable being more than an arbitrary constant 'a', as compared to the probability being greater than zero. The spread of the $exponential$ and $geometric$ *probability density function* and *probability mass function* curve is unchanged but the curve moves up by 'a' units if we are after trying to find the probability of the random variable being greater than 'a'.